# How to efficiently pick the i-th item from 10,000 Python lists and turn them into a list efficiently?

Tags: python, histogram

I am working on a Monte Carlo algorithm.  Essentially,, since time is involved, each iteration produces a list with 50 items covering 50 years of simulation. I append these so that I have a list that contains 10,000 elements, each of which is a list of 50 numbers.

Now, of course, I need to put the data, for each year,  into a list itself of 10,000 items so I can do the annual histogram analysis.

As a simple example, if I had 5 runs of 3 years of data, I might have a list that looks like so:

```
[[1,2,3, 4,5], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5], [2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9]]
```

and I need to get it into a list that looks like so:

```
[[1, 1.1, 2.1], [2, 2.2, 2.6], [3, 3.3, 2.7], [4, 4.4, 2.8], [5, 5.5, 2.9]]
```

Obviously I could brute force this with a double loop, but with 500,000 data points I am looking for something more efficient and Pythonic.

Does anyone have enough knowledge of the internals (or packages) that would make this happen quickly and efficiently?

Comment: Lists by nature are inefficient. I suggest implementing some sort of hash set.

Comment: @emsimpson92 don't know what you are talking about. Lists are extremely efficient if you know the index you require.

Comment: It seems I misread the question. I was under the impression that the index was not known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` or `numpy.transpose` (probably faster):

```
d = [[1,2,3, 4,5], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5], [2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9]]

zip(*d) # returns a generator in Python3, use list on top of it if needed

import numpy as np
np.transpose(d) # returns a np.array, which will behave more or less the same as a Python list
# or simply something like 
arr = np.array(d)
arr[:,i] # returns the i-th values in each row
```

Comment: numpy.transpose is amazingly fast.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could `zip` the lists:

```
x = [[1,2,3, 4,5], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5], [2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9]]

y = zip(*x) #Unpacking elements of x before zipping

print(list(y))
>>>[(1, 1.1, 2.5), (2, 2.2, 2.6), (3, 3.3, 2.7), (4, 4.4, 2.8), (5, 5.5, 2.9)]
```

Comment: Upvoted, however the OP should use `itertools.izip` for large lists if s/he is using <Python3

Answer (score 1):

Lists are flexible items; as a result, they're slow.  Since you have a fixed-width environment, use an enhanced structure.  For starters, a NumPy 2D array should help.  You don't have to force it into another orientation: just use the vector expressions provided, and force NumPy to do the needed vectorizations (assuming that your processor supports those).